# looping in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have this simple configuration in Spring Batch for the first step:

```
<batch:job id="collaborationJob" >
    <batch:step id="collaborationJobStep1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="collaborationAlertReader" processor="WriteCollaborationPruningProcessor" writer="alertCollaborationPruningWriter"
                commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="*" to="collaborationJobStep2" />
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="collaborationJobStep4"/>
    </batch:step>
```

If I  read a number of rows < 10 in itemReader everything is fine, but if the number of rows is >= 10 I enter in a repeation loop:

```
2015-09-29 17:02:40,782 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=1332, version=878, name=collaborationJobStep1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=8780, filterCount=0, writeCount=8780 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=878, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,786 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=879>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,786 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback] - <Preparing chunk execution for StepContext: org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext@664020c7>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,786 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback] - <Chunk execution starting: queue size=0>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,787 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Starting repeat context.>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,787 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=1>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=2>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=3>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=4>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=5>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=6>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=7>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=8>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=9>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat operation about to start at count=10>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,791 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] - <Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,793 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet] - <Inputs not busy, ended: false>

2015-09-29 17:02:40,793 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] - <Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=10, written=10, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]>
```

What's wrong with my configuration?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm currently having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some policies applied to the chunks (even `DefaultResultCompletionPolicy`) are waiting for the end of reading (`read()` method from the reader needs to return `null` when they are nothing to read anymore).

So check your `read` method from your reader `collaborationAlertReader` if it returns `null` when the reading is done (for example, if the `read` method return an empty list, your step will go in an infinite loop).